# On Azure Cognitive Search, how to support Concatenated words or split words

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently using Azure Cognitive Search. I hope it can support Concatenated words or split words. For example: If I make search "mapletree", I hope that results containing "map tree" are also shown, but it doesn't happen. I have try the fuzzy search such as (mapletree~2 OR mapletree^3). But no luck.
I also search "map tree", I hope that results containing "maptree" are also shown, but it doesn't happen either. Does anyone have suggestions or solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cognitive Search does not support concatenated words or split words by default.
However, to search concatenated words or split words in Azure Cognitive Search, you can create a custom analyzer that uses the EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2 to generate tokens with different lengths.

Below is an example of custom analyzer with the EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2:

```py
{
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "myCustomAnalyzer",
      "charFilters": [],
      "tokenizer": "keyword_v2",
      "tokenFilters": ["lowercase", "my_edgeNGram"]
    }
  ],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
      "name": "my_edgeNGram",
      "minGram": 2,
      "maxGram": 25,
      "side": "front"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then assign this custom analyzer to the fields you want to search on. This should help you match concatenated words or split words in your search queries.

Based on the information I have used analyzer with sample data and got the below required result.

[image]

For more details you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching) on partial term search and custom analyzer.